# Parametrizing distance between objects in an array

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

guys. New to geometric nodes here.

I have the following objects, which are positioned manually by me

[image]

Basically I am trying to figure out a way such that the distance between the objects increases/decreases as u go down the array, and it should depend on the index of the object in the array, for example:

*d= i^2/2 where i is the index and d is the distance from the start point.*

And it has to be parameterised using geometric nodes so that I can change the no of objects and the distance equation

I was able to create a normal array using geometric nodes but have no idea how to take the index of each element in the array to use in the equation

[image]

It would be great if you can refer me some links or provide a solution.

Comment: This is probably simpler than you think.. what variation do you want in your equations, though? Making those _anything you like_ via the GN  interface would be a bit tricky..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple indeed:

[image]

...

Comment: thanks. I was trying a similar thing without the accumulate field node and was stuck for a long time. Its simpler than I thought it would be